# Are there places of learning in the Forgotten Realms I could use in my backstory?

Tags: forgotten-realms

I am playing a High Elf with the Sage Background and the specialization of Researcher and I would like to develop more details about what university or similar institution I might frequent. My character is from the Storm Coast. Are there any universities in the region, or that would be sensible to have travelled to?

Comment: Do you mean the sword coast?

Comment: Yes. Too much Game of Thrones. Sorry!

Comment: I don't think it would really change the answer(s) here, but when talking about Faerun, calling the elves with their subrace (sun elves, I guess) might make your questions more clear ;)

Comment: Terrific suggestion! Thank you! I am a star elf. My special interests of study are arcane lore, enchanted objects, and history including lost cultures and genealogy. I do a lot of field research as well as book research.

Answer (score 12):

The biggest center of learning in the Forgotten Realms is Candlekeep, which is just south of Baldur's Gate on the Sword Coast.

Another good candidate would be Silverymoon in the North. It has always been the academic and magical center of the region, and a large part of its population is made of elves.

Comment: Now I HAVE to have a *Silverymoo* in my next campaign setting. "The world capital of dairy farming ! Don't miss the Great Milk Festival on spring equinox !"

Comment: This is wonderful and very helpful! Thank you!